# rounding numbers powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to make the code round the number if it crosses the number .4
For example 2.4 = 2, 2.5 = 3
That is, it does not round up to 4, but after it rounds

Comment: Rounding rules are sometimes surprising. See .Net [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0) about what's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` additional parameter:

```
[Math]::Round(2.5, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) # 3
[Math]::Round(0.5, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) # 1
[Math]::Round(2.49, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) # 2, because 2.49 is not midpoint
```

By default, `[Math]::Round` uses `[MidpointRounding]::ToEven` if not specified.

Please see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) for details.